# How to read array environment variable in application.conf?

Tags: arrays, scala, environment-variables, typesafe-config

I would like to define in `application.conf` a variable which will be a list of strings. Currently in application.conf I have something like this:

```
some.env.variable = ["a", "b"]
```

I tried:

```
some.env.variable = ${?I_AM_ENV}.split(",")
```

when `I_AM_ENV = a,b`  but it didn't work.

I get an error when loading app:

```
Wrong value type at 'some.env.variable', expecting: list but got: string
```

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/typesafehub/config?

Comment: yes. version 1.3.0

Comment: Read it as a simple string in the config file and parse it in Scala. Not sure HOCON is the place to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 8):

Took a while but we found it.

`application.conf`

```
    access-control-allow-origin = ["http://localhost:4444"]
    access-control-allow-origin = ${?CLIENT_DOMAIN}
```

```
    export CLIENT_DOMAIN.0=http://localhost:3000
    export CLIENT_DOMAIN.1=http://localhost:3001
```

Comment: This works, thanks! It seems the double declaration is required, but you can leave the first one empty if there's no reasonable default, e.g.:

`foo = []`
`foo = ${FOO}`

`export FOO.0=bar`
`export FOO.1=baz`

Answer (score 5):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/lightbend/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides):

```
// in your env
export OPTIONAL_A='"b", "c"'

// in application.conf
path = [ "a", ${?OPTIONAL_A} ]
```

should evaluate `path` to `["a", "b", "c"]`

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers didn't work for me (using Play 2.6.17), so this answer did the trick: [HOCON array substitution from envs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65416875/1159167) (check the **Maximum Flexibility** section)

```bash
# Optionally set separated environment vars for each array item
export I_AM_ENV_0=a
export I_AM_ENV_1=b
```

Then, on `application.conf`, use substitution to set items within the array:

```
# it works also if the env. var. were not set
some.env.variable = [ ${?I_AM_ENV_0}, ${?I_AM_ENV_1} ]
```