# HOCON array substitution from envs

Tags: typesafe-config, hocon

I am using the HOCON config format and parsing lib is from typesafe.Config. HOCON supports env vars injections and overrides. like:

```
my.config = "asd"
my.config = ${?MY_ENV_VAR}
```

this will substitute the default value "asd" if there is a env var called MY_ENV_VAR presented. however I can't seem to find any good way to do list env substitution. like:

```
my.config = [1,2,3,4]
my.config = ${?MY_ENV_LIST}
```

because by default, env vars from outside will be default to string, so `[1,2,3,4]` will be considered as "[1,2,3,4]" from the library's perspective, therefore it can't be seen as a list and will produce runtime error like this:

> com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: application.conf: 5:
>   application.boolliststring has type STRING rather than LIST
>
> at
>   com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:133)
>     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)
>     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)
>     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
>     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
>     at
>   com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getList(SimpleConfig.java:212)

anyone has any idea what is the proper way to do list env substitution in HOCON format? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the env var `MY_ENV_LIST` contain ?

Comment: @ToYonos MY_ENV_LIST='[1,2,3,4]', sourced from env vars. since env vars can only be in string type, therefore causing this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The Answer

Going from one environment variable to an array is not possible out of the box, as the other answer states.

You could re-parse the string loaded from config:

```
// application.conf
my.config = "list = [1, 2, 3]"
my.config = ${?LIST_VAR}

// code
String listString = ConfigFactory.load().getString("my.config")
ConfigFactory.parseString(listString).getIntList("list")
```

Then set `LIST_VAR='list = [4, 5, 6]'` to override the defaults. Note that you need `list =`  because an object is
required at the top level of hocon, you can't use an array.

### - or -

If your data is clean enough, you could just split on `,`s:

```
// application.conf
my.config = "foo,bar,baz"
my.config = ${?CSV_VAR}

// java code
String csvString = ConfigFactory.load().getString("my.config")
String[] parameters = csvString.split(",")
```

Then, just set `CSV_VAR=bing,bang,boom,pow` (no `[]`).

## Further Reading

On the other hand, if you use separate environment variables for each value, there are several options.

### No Defaults

The simplest, if you don't need defaults, looks like this:

```
my.config = [ ${?MY_ENV_VAR}, ${?MY_ENV_VAR_TWO} ]
```

Any values that are not defined are omitted.

### Adding to defaults

If you only need to add to default values, you could use `+=` [syntax](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#the--field-separator):

```
my.config = [1, 2]
my.config += ${?MY_ENV_VAR}
my.config += ${?MY_ENV_VAR_TWO}
```

Any values that are not defined are not added to the array.

### Maximum Flexibility

The most flexible option I've found is to use [positional syntax](https://github.com/lightbend/config#set-array-values-outside-configuration-files) in your `application.conf` (or `reference.conf` or `-D` options or anywhere else you provide config):

```
my.config.0 = 1                    // always set to 1  
my.config.1 = 2                    // defaults to 2 if MY_ENV_VAR is not set
my.config.1 = ${?MY_ENV_VAR}
my.config.2 = ${?MY_ENV_VAR_TWO}   // totally optional
my.config.3 = ${MY_ENV_VAR_THREE}  // doesn't have ?, so it is required
```

Any values that are defined will be included, any that are not will be skipped over. For example, if `MY_ENV_VAR=4`,
`MY_ENV_VAR_THREE=6`, and `MY_ENV_VAR_TWO` is not set, the resulting list will be `[1, 4, 6]`.

### List of objects

You can even define objects within the list, like this:

```
my.nested.0.myField = 1
my.nested.0.otherField = "hello"
my.nested.1.myField = 2
my.nested.1.myField = ${?MY_INT}
my.nested.1.otherField = "goodbye"
my.nested.1.otherField = ${?MY_STRING}
my.nested.2.myField = ${OTHER_INT}       // Note lack of ?
my.nested.2.otherField = ${OTHER_STRING} // Note lack of ?
```

One catch with a list of config objects, at least in my testing, is all items need to be completely defined. That is why
the fields that don't have defaults are required substitutions. If `MY_INT=99`, `MY_STRING` is not set, `OTHER_INT=100`,
and `OTHER_STRING=foo`, the above renders to:

```
other {
  nested = [
    { myField = 1, otherField = "hello" },
    { myField = 99, otherField = "goodbye" },
    { myField = 100, otherField = "foo" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Cool investigation! Thanks! Didn't know that HOCON is so powerful

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

From Hocon [docs](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md):

> environment variables always become a string value, though if an app asks for another type automatic type conversion would kick in

A note from same docs related to automatic type conversions:

> The following type conversions should NOT be performed:
>
> ...
>
> anything to array, with the exception of numerically-indexed object to array
>
> Converting objects and arrays to and from strings is tempting, but in practical situations raises thorny issues of quoting and double-escaping.